# adding number in C using pointers, without taking variable?

Tags: c, pointers

Can we add two numbers using pointers but without using any variable like a,b?
I mean, generally, we take two variables and store it in pointer... but is it possible to the numbers without taking variable or can we take pointer variable?

Comment: Please specify the language and any code that you may have tried.

Comment: The values are actually stored in memory. The variables are names given to that memory. Pointers are variables that store addresses of those memory, usually in the case of dynamic memory allocation

Comment: actually i'm trying it in C language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer :

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 10;
int *b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*b = 20;
printf("%ld + %ld = %ld\n", *a , *b , *a + *b);
```